# Why pymongo aggregate method returns CommandCursor where find method returns Cursor

Tags: count, cursor, pymongo

I'm tried to use count() on output cursor of aggregate and failed with 'count" is not found in commandcursor where as count works on output cursor of find().

On looking further found that, find() is returning cursor type and aggregate is returning commandcursor. And cursor type has count() attribute but Commandcursor does not.

Though return data types (list of Dictionary types) are same for both find() and aggregate, why is there a separate cursor type of aggregate?

-Subhash Reddy